# I can't get Solarized Dark scheme to work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, themes, gnome-terminal, preferences

I have followed the instructions both [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html) and [here](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) and I can't get this scheme to work.  I'm specifically interested in the dark scheme but I'm not seeing any changes at all.  I've looked through the Profile Preferences but there's nothing there either.  The /gnome-terminal-colors-solarized directory is created.  I run ./install.sh. and I've tried ./set_dark.sh and neither do anything.  What am I missing?